# OpenCV C++ doesn't return false when capture is not working

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm working with an IP camera and need to know when the capture failed. According to the OpenCV documentation, the *VideoCapture::read(OutputArray image)* should return **false** when no frames has been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file)    but this is not happening. When my camera disconnects, my code got stuck in the read function. I need to know when the capture failed. How can this be done? My code follows bellow:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    String ptzCam = "rtsp://user:password@ip:port/videoMain";

    VideoCapture cap(ptzCam);  // open the default camera
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("capture", 1);

    for (;;) {
        Mat frame;

        if (cap.read(frame)) {
            cout << "Capturing... " << endl;
            imshow("capture", frame);           
        }
        else {
            cout << "Capture is not opened." << endl;           
        }   

        if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
    }

    cap.release();
    destroyAllWindows();
}
```

Comment: does it freeze (probably a driver problem) or is just no image returned? You can test if(frame.empty()) doSomething; in the latter case.

Comment: It freezes and the code got stucked in cap.read(frame). Gonna try to check if the frame is empty and try to update the driver. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: if it freezes you can't check whether the result is empty (because the result is never happening). I guess it is a driver problem of your camera and not strictly a openCV problem. Probably you can't do anything... Which OS do you use?

Comment: I'm using windows 7.

Comment: you could try to open the camera with the test application of `InputLibrary` and check whether the same behaviour occurs if you unplug the camera there. Or same for DirectShow, VLC or different applications which can open your camera.

Answer (score 1):

You shall try following code:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap;
cv::Mat frm;

cap.open(0);
if (!cap.isOpened())
    // error handling
while (true) {
    if (!cap.grab() || !cap.retrieve(frm) || frm.empty()) {
        // error handling
    }
    // cv::imshow and cv::waitKey or any other frm manipulations
}
```

You may learn about cv::VideoCapture member funcs here: [cv::VideoCapture::grab()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ae38c2a053d39d6b20c9c649e08ff0146), [cv::VideoCapture::retrieve()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a9ac7f4b1cdfe624663478568486e6712)

Comment: Could you please explain what cap.grab() and cap.retrieve do?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently playing around with OpenCV myself and I was trying to figure out how to handle disconnecting and then reconnecting an USB camera. When I used the `cap.isOpened()` function after unplugging the USB, I noticed nothing changes the return value. After unplugging the camera I also noticed that trying to read an frame caused crashes. This made it so I couldn't plug the camera back in and have it playing again. But the code below made it so that I could dis/reconnect the camera without having the program crash on me.

```
while (true) { //loop for showing camera footage
    if (cap.read(frame)) { //check if there is an frame to read
        imshow("something", frame); //show the frame
        if (waitKey(1000 / 60) >= 0) 
            break;
    }else{ //if you can't read the frame (because camera is disconnected) enter an loop
        while (true) {
            VideoCapture newCapture(0); //create an new capture
            if (!newCapture.isOpened()) //check if the new capture is open or not
                cout << "camera is unavailable" << endl;
            else {
                cout << "camera seems available" << endl;
                cap = newCapture; //if the new capture is open set it as the origional capture
                break; //break from the loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```